# Number of results without 1 condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

There is complicated MySql SELECT query:

```
SELECT id, login, date...
FROM tab1
  LEFT JOIN tab2
  LEFT JOIN tab3
  LEFT JOIN tab4
  ...
WHERE
 condition1 = value
 condition2 = value
 ...
ORDER ...
LIMIT ...
```

**I need to get the number of results from same select but without condition1 and limit. What is the best solution? Is there better solution than just make 2 SELECT query?**

Comment: it would be helpful if you post the full query as well as some sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Pass condition1 in as a parameter and use boolean logic to include it or exclude it:

```
...
WHERE
condition1 = value OR condition1 IS NULL
```

If you don't want to use condition1 set it to null or pass in a null parameter.
This ensures that the SELECT doesnt care about the first condition.  It then evaluates to:

```
...
WHERE
FALSE OR TRUE
```

And boolean logic states when one value is true the result is true.  If you need condition1 pass an actual value and the result becomes

```
...
WHERE
TRUE OR FALSE
```

This evaluates to TRUE as well and ensures your condition is met because you've filtered on value.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a `COUNT` of the number of rows you have to perform another query, you cannot return an aggregate result and actual rows in one go.

In your case you are also changing the `WHERE` clause so it's not possible to count the rows at the client side either.

If you are concerned about performance you need to show the actual query you are using for anyone to be able to give help.